# Can Fieldvalue.serverTimestamp() represents the time that is 'X' seconds in the future?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Essentially, I would like to call a Firebase Cloud Function to put into a document the **'deadline'** value (which is only tens of seconds away from the time of doc creation), so that the client app reading the doc can be sure to to take an action before the deadline. From what I understand, serverTimestap is a token, so not sure how to go about doing what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldValue.serverTimestamp` can only represent the current moment in time, at the time a write takes place at the Firestore bcakend.  It can not do anything else.

If you want to add or remove time from that, you will have to write `FieldValue.serverTimestamp` to a document, read the document back to get the actual time from it, perform math on that date, then write it back.

Answer (score 2):

While Doug is right about not being able to store a calculated value based on the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp` at document creation, I'd recommend an alternative solution. In cases like this, I store two values in the document:

1. The timestamp when the document was created/updated.
2. The offset of when the document expires (in your scenario).

Both of these can be set at creation time, they can be validated easily, and you can then perform the necessary calculation between them in your queries or application code.